# How can I write Ubuntu apps in Java?

Tags: java, application-development

I am new to linux.

I want to develop apps for Ubuntu desktop and mobile using Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to develop apps for Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8209/what-is-the-best-way-to-develop-apps-for-ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks manish , i just want to use java not python "What is the best way to develop apps for Ubuntu? " says about python ,kindly tell me what are the steps to be taken to develop apps, like what IDE to be used and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If You wish to use Java, then take a look at Eclipse IDE and/or NetBeans IDE. Also Adroid SDK is available for free, and it uses Java as well.

Regards

BTW: read the whole topic before you downvote

Answer (score 10):

Because Java bytecode is portable, there isn't much difference between writing a Java app for Windows and writing one for Ubuntu.  You can use either [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/swing/index.html), [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) or [JavaFx](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/index.html) for your GUI, and [Eclipse](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/eclipse/) as an IDE.

You can also write native-looking apps in Java with [JGIR](https://live.gnome.org/JGIR).  JGIR will let you use [GTK+ 3](https://live.gnome.org/JGIR/SampleCode) to build your application.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [java-gnome](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/NEWS.html#4.1.1) project .   But, even thought that exists, going with JavaFX still might be a better option to invest your time in.

Comment: java-gnome has been superseded by JGIR