# I want to develop for linux, where do I start?

Tags: application-development, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to develop apps for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8209/what-is-the-best-way-to-develop-apps-for-ubuntu)

So, I am currently running Ubuntu 10.04 and I would like to start developing for Linux. I am already developing some stuff for Mac OS, so it would be great if I could use Objective C.

If that is not possible, it's not that big of a problem, so my main question is: Where do I start? What kind of developer Kits are available?

I've heard of GNU Step, are there any good beginners tutorials for it (the GUI) and for the Interface Builder?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Objective C and GNU step are not widely used in Ubuntu. That doesn't mean that you can't use them, but don't expect to find lots of support. Please check this question for some answers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/8209/what-is-the-best-way-to-develop-apps-for-ubuntu

Comment: Which language should I learn and which environment should I use?

Comment: Most used languages are python and C. In the linked question you have lots of resources, please check them. Specially http://developer.ubuntu.com/