# Beginning Developing Applications For Ubuntu

Tags: programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to develop apps for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8209/what-is-the-best-way-to-develop-apps-for-ubuntu)

First of all thanks for reading this question:
What programming language is used for developing Ubuntu applications? In other words, I would like to begin producing application for Ubuntu but don't know where to begin, any help would be great, especially tutorials.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Try looking here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/8209/what-is-the-best-way-to-develop-apps-for-ubuntu